# How to use custom variables in Product descriptions?

Tags: product, custom, variables

Many products need to have the same or partly the same description, in order to be able to edit them all at once it would come in handy to make use of the magento custom variables. They work in CMS blocks but I was not able to make them show their contend in product descriptions.
Is there a way to achieve this without reinventing the wheel?

Comment: I'm afraid not, although, if many products contain same description, I'd suggest moving that part into static block and calling that block in view.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. I found this and will check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20508731/how-to-call-specific-static-blocks-inside-product-descriptions-in-magento

Answer (score 3):

If i understood your question right. First of all create one custom variable called "panel-width" fill all the details in variable.

Now you've to call this variable in product view page `..catalog/product/view.phtml` and call below code wherever you want to implement.

```
<!-- get custom variables -->
<?php $panelWidth = Mage::getModel('core/variable')->loadByCode('panel-width')->getValue('plain'); ?>
```

Here `$panel-widht` is vaiable code. Simple use variable `$panelWidth` to display your content. Use this example with your custom variable values and need.

Comment: Hi, I looks like with this method I will be only able to use variable "panel-width" in all products. What I was looking for was a method to use different
variables for different types of products, where I can call the variable from within the product description field in back end.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. After some more searching I came across this little extension:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/13663/

We are using 1.9.0.1 it and it works.

Comment: If the extension works for you, that's great, but it contains unnecessary class rewrites and might conflict with other product related extensions. I wrote a similar module, using only an observer for `catalog_controller_product_view` that applies the CMS filter on description and other product attributes before they are displayed. Not published (yet), I'm just saying it's possible ;)

Answer (score 0):

The following module will help you not only with product attributes but also with category attributes. It works great with terms and conditions section.

[Custom Variable for Product, Category and Terms & Conditions sections](https://www.scommerce-mage.com/magento-custom-variable-anywhere.html)